# Problems to cite properly figures in tufte-handout class

Tags: cross-referencing, tufte

I'm working in a handout where I include few pictures with the helping of the environments `figure` and `marginfigure`. But my problem is that when I compile my handout the reference's number of one of the figures doesn't prints in the PDF.

Here is a MWE

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames,table}{xcolor}
\documentclass[]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage[LGRx,TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenx}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,spanish,activeacute,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext,amsthm}
%\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{array,multirow,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\sisetup{
%output-decimal-marker = {,},
detect-weight= true, 
range-units = brackets,
list-final-separator = { \translate{and} },
list-pair-separator = { \translate{and} },
range-phrase = { \translate{to (numerical range)} },
}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{graphicx,subfigure,etex,tikz,pgfplots}
\graphicspath{{./imagen/}}

\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,spanish,textsize=footnotesize]{todonotes}

\usepackage{acronym}    
\acrodef{AHA}{American Heart Asociation}
\newcommand{\greek}[1]{{\selectlanguage{polutonikogreek}#1}}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent nec urna at lectus facilisis fringilla eu vel odio. Pellentesque luctus massa vel ipsum feugiat hendrerit. Suspendisse tristique malesuada consequat. Donec mi turpis, faucibus sit amet commodo sed, condimentum at sapien. Suspendisse consectetur urna dolor. Nulla vel libero at tortor suscipit accumsan. Donec sit amet mauris a ipsum malesuada molestie. Nulla fermentum nunc in metus pellentesque aliquet. Aenean hendrerit sem eu dui ornare, at interdum urna dictum. Donec nisi urna, varius eget consectetur ac, cursus non velit. Vestibulum eget sollicitudin dui, non interdum lectus. Vivamus eleifend euismod orci, sit amet posuere mauris placerat id.

Integer gravida laoreet massa sed scelerisque. Aenean scelerisque suscipit metus non suscipit. Aenean arcu metus, mollis eu sagittis et, cursus in justo. Nullam mollis auctor bibendum. Integer nec congue est, vitae scelerisque ipsum. Nullam ultrices sapien orci, eget vestibulum turpis euismod eget. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vivamus sed quam id risus consequat gravida id a enim. Duis non nulla ac neque fringilla molestie. Mauris vel sagittis sapien. Morbi in posuere nisl. Vivamus consequat accumsan leo ut malesuada. Integer pretium fringilla suscipit. Suspendisse gravida urna ut luctus lobortis. Nunc at odio vel neque sagittis pharetra at a quam~\ref{fig:esqAHA}. Mauris quis ligula porttitor, mollis dui at, rutrum enim.

\begin{figure*}[htb]
\begin{flushleft}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{F5_large}
\end{flushleft}
\caption[Drawing of cross-sections]{Drawing of cross-sections of identical, most proximal part of six left anterior descending coronary arteries. The morphology of the intima ranges from adaptive intimal thickening always present in this lesion-prone location to a type VI lesion in advanced atherosclerotic disease. Other cross-sections show sequence of atherosclerotic lesion types that may lead to type VI. Identical morphologies may be found in other lesion-prone parts of the coronary and many other arteries.}
\label{fig:esqAHA}
\end{figure*}

Mauris tristique imperdiet orci id rhoncus. Nam neque est, pellentesque non aliquam ac, eleifend nec lectus. Integer mollis porta elit, non pharetra diam. Duis eget est hendrerit, iaculis urna id, rutrum dui. Vivamus egestas sem a diam consequat commodo. Donec quis purus ultrices, sagittis eros nec, sagittis enim. Quisque egestas lorem ac pretium aliquet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sed posuere leo. Mauris odio velit, commodo at commodo id, rutrum nec justo. Donec in elit quis purus vestibulum scelerisque vitae eu lorem.

\begin{figure*}[htb]

\begin{flushleft}
\includegraphics[width=4in]{F4_large}
\end{flushleft}
\caption[Flow diagram]{Flow diagram in center column indicates pathways in evolution and progression of human atherosclerotic lesions. Roman numerals indicate histologically characteristic types of lesions enumerated in Table 2 and defined at left of flow diagram. The direction of arrows indicates sequence in which characteristic morphologies may change. From type I to type IV, changes in lesion morphology occur primarily because of increasing accumulation of lipid. The loop between types V and VI illustrates how lesions increase in thickness when thrombotic deposits form on their surfaces. Thrombotic deposits may form repeatedly over varied time spans in the same location and may be the principal mechanism for gradual occlusion of medium-sized arteries. }
\label{fig:sixAHA}
\end{figure*}

Phasellus commodo sed metus ac hendrerit. Ut feugiat molestie sem in viverra. Mauris sed suscipit erat, non pretium est. Cras auctor massa sit amet nulla aliquam, et dapibus ante lacinia. Donec et tempor risus, dignissim vulputate ipsum. Curabitur dui eros, vulputate euismod sollicitudin quis, aliquet eget nisi. Fusce id auctor tellus, quis congue dolor. Nam vel dignissim est. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nam eget arcu ut tellus adipiscing sodales (see the figure~\ref{fig:sixAHA}). Pellentesque sed nunc urna.

Praesent blandit purus vitae tortor vestibulum, sit amet pharetra diam vestibulum. Phasellus sit amet gravida elit. Nulla laoreet blandit libero. Nam adipiscing congue adipiscing. Integer a nulla sit amet tortor scelerisque placerat at at lectus. Quisque tincidunt nisi in iaculis egestas. In ligula augue, aliquet a dui eu, malesuada rhoncus leo. Donec sit amet luctus ipsum. Nullam cursus erat erat, sit amet elementum lorem tempus nec. Ut nec augue porta, tristique justo eu, feugiat elit. Fusce semper, sapien feugiat tempor sodales, nulla justo laoreet sem, id placerat tortor elit ut erat. Nullam vitae nunc urna. Duis laoreet enim id metus egestas, rhoncus congue justo feugiat. 
\end{document}
```

Both figures where taken from [here](http://atvb.ahajournals.org/content/15/9/1512.figures-only) and are the 4 and 5 respectively.

In my pdf the reference to the second figure doesn't print any number, and it happens in every reference I make of that. It's strange. All the other features works fine. Now I'm working in a PC with MS Windows XP and MikTeX 2.9 updated, so I don't know what's wrong. I have more figures and all works fine with the others.

That's all, regards.

Answer (score 3):

Your usage of `LGRx` shows that your TeX system is not up-to-date. The current best way is just to avoid declaring any encoding for Greek. Update your system and modify the preamble as follows:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames,table}{xcolor}
\documentclass[]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{etex} % should go first
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,spanish,activeacute,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}
```

Also I don't recommend `utf8x`.

Your problem is due to loading `subfigure` which has been deprecated for almost ten years, now.

Load `subfig`, instead, without `caption`, which doesn't cooperate well with the `tufte` classes:

```
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
```

The syntax is pretty much the same, except that you say

```
\subfloat
```

instead of `\subfigure` and `\subtable`.

Also, load `hyperref` last.

Comment: Thanks, I have problems for compile now because of my text in greek.

Comment: @Aradnix Changing `subfigure` as indicated should work also in the old setup of `babel` for Greek. I tried with TeX Live 2012 and it works.

Comment: Well actually my computer with linux has some problems (not with TeX) and I can't work on it now. I have only MikTeX, is there a way to fix it with MikTeX?

Comment: @Aradnix It should work fine with MiKTeX provided it is reasonably up to date. The suggestions in egreg's answer aren't specific to Linux or any other platform...

Comment: Well we can install TeXlive in windows too, but in the institute we have MikTeX instead of TeXlive, so as I'm unable to change that I prefer a solution inside MikTeX. At home I use a TeXLive distro running on linux without problems, but my pc is in reparation right now.